# Backtracking solution for palindrome partitioning issue with displacement of sub-string in the output

Tags: java, string, recursion, backtracking

I am solving the question of [palindrome partitioning on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/#/description).

I have written a recursive solution which prints the correct Lists of substrings but for one of the test cases, the order in the list does not match the expected output.

**Input:**

> cbbbcc

**Output:**

> [["c","b","b","b","c","c"],["b","b","b","c","cc"],["b","c","bb","c","c"],["b","bb","c","cc"],["c","bb","b","c","c"],["bb","b","c","cc"],["c","bbb","c","c"],["bbb","c","cc"],["cbbbc","c"]]

**Expected:**

> [["c","b","b","b","c","c"],["c","b","b","b","cc"],["c","b","bb","c","c"],["c","b","bb","cc"],["c","bb","b","c","c"],["c","bb","b","cc"],["c","bbb","c","c"],["c","bbb","cc"],["cbbbc","c"]]

I am not able to figure out why is my recursive call shifting the first element "c" in this example.

```
public class Solution {

public List<List<String>> partition(String s) {

    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    backTrack(result, new ArrayList<String>(), s);

    return result;
}

private void backTrack(List<List<String>> result, List<String> cur, String s){

    if(s.length() == 0)
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(cur));

    /* length = i+1 */
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(isPalindrome(s.substring(0, i+1))){
            cur.add(s.substring(0, i+1));
            backTrack(result, cur, s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
            cur.remove(s.substring(0, i+1));
        }
    }

}

private boolean isPalindrome(String s){
    int start = 0, end = s.length() - 1;
    char[] schars = s.toCharArray();

    while(start < end){
        if(schars[start] != schars[end])
            return false;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I did go through an example and as per my logic, I do not see any reason that "c" should be displaced as in the output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because of the way you expect `add` and `remove` to behave with your List.

Initially, you are building up cur from s (here *cbbbcc*):

```
s           cur
1. cbbbcc   []
2. bbbcc    [c]
3. bbcc     [c, b]
4. bcc      [c, b, b]
5. cc       [c, b, b, b]
6. c        [c, b, b, b, c]
7.          [c, b, b, b, c, c]
```

Now, the calls to `backTrack()` return in the reverse order 7, 6, 5, ...

Thus, this line:

```
cur.remove(s.substring(0, i+1));
```

is first run with the substring **"c"**.

Ideally, your code should remove the rightmost **"c"** from *cur*. But the remove method removes the first **"c"** that it encounters, which is at position 0. From here on, your ordering is always wrong.

The easiest solution would be to always add to the first position to match the default behaviour for `remove()`. You would need to invert the String before using it in this way, though.

I've modified your code appropriately, here:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Solution {

  public List<List<String>> partition(String s) {

      List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
      backTrack(result, new ArrayList<String>(), new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());  // EDIT 1: Invert String

      return result;
  }

  private void backTrack(List<List<String>> result, List<String> cur, String s) {
      if(s.length() == 0) result.add(new ArrayList<>(cur));

      for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
          if(isPalindrome(s.substring(0, i+1))){
              cur.add(0, s.substring(0, i+1)); // EDIT 2: Add to beginning of list
              backTrack(result, cur, s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
              cur.remove(s.substring(0, i+1));
          }
      }
  }

  private boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
      int start = 0, end = s.length() - 1;
      char[] schars = s.toCharArray();

      while(start < end){
          if(schars[start] != schars[end])
              return false;
          start++;
          end--;
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

You can run in online [here](https://repl.it/JNx4) or below.

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/JNx4/0.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, instead of reversing the string and adding to the left of the list, you could simply remove() by finding the rightmost occurrence of the character in the list.

Comment: Yes, it worked after I replaced the line cur.remove(s.substring(0, i+1)); with cur.remove(cur.size() - 1);

Comment: @Jedi is there a way for me to visualize the "backtrack" part? I'm having a hard time visualize how are we "backtracking" in this problem. Thank you

Comment: I'm just reusing OP's nomenclature and naming schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems like you were removing the leftmost element instead of the rightmost element.The following should suffice:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OneSolution {


private List<List<String>> partition(String s) {

    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    backTrack(result, new ArrayList<String>(), s);

    return result;
}

private void backTrack(List<List<String>> result, List<String> cur, String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(cur));

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && s.length() > 0; i++) {
        if (isPalindrome(s.substring(0, i + 1))) {
            cur.add(s.substring(0, i + 1));
            backTrack(result, cur, s.substring(i + 1, s.length()));
            Collections.reverse(cur);  //Reverse String remove 1st element
            cur.remove(s.substring(0, i + 1));
            Collections.reverse(cur);  //Reverse back to original
        }
    }

}

private boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
    String rev = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
    return rev.equals(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OneSolution os = new OneSolution();
    System.out.println(os.partition("cbbbcc"));
    System.out.println(os.partition("bab"));
}

}
```

[Verify](https://repl.it/JNx4/1)

Comment: @Jedi Oh yes, I checked the exact order. My mistake!